# how to provide proper back navigation with fragment on clicking the home button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I would like to provide back navigation while clicking on the Home button of Actionbar.
 **In the Host Fragment**

```
((MainActivity)this.getActivity()).fragment_Actualités=new Fragment_Actualités();
         fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame,((MainActivity)this.getActivity()).fragment_Actualités);
         fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
         fragmentTransaction.commit();
        ((MainActivity)this.getActivity()).fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
        ((MainActivity)this.getActivity()).supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
```

**In the Host Activity**

```
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
    // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action buttons
    int id=0;
    if(id==item.getItemId()){
         if(id== R.id.home)
        {
            this.onBackPressed();
            return true;}

        }
```

*The super.OnBackPressed works fine when I click on the back button it goes back as expected*
How can I make it worked ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
[fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStackImmediate())

Comment: try but it doesn't change something. Thank's for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
this.onBackPressed();
```

to:

```
onBackPressed();
```

and extends FragmentActivity if you don't do it already

Comment: it doesn't changed anything changing this.onBackPressed by onBackPressed.But thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Reading your code again I think found the issue, you are assigning 0 to id so when you compere with item.getItemId() always return false. Try with this code

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    if (itemId == android.R.id.home) {
        this.onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for such effort :) it's very kind. I try also what you suggested too.but it doesn't works too.only the back button of the device works but when I click on the app's home button it's doesn't go back to the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved it,
the matter was that, I had 2 MenuItems, the Settings and the Home One's .
So if only write **R.id.Home** it won't work but when changed to **android.R.id.Home** it works !!!
with the same code